# NHibernate 3.3.1 with Medium Trust error

Tags: nhibernate, medium-trust

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.1 in medium trust. It throw a Security Exception.
In the NHibernate 3.3.1 say that it is compatible with medium trust.

Has it any prerequisite?

Comment: I use NH3.3.1 in medium trust (Rackspace cloud), what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: The error is in portuguese:
"Falha na solicitação da permissão de tipo 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using the [NHibernate.DependencyInjection](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.DependencyInjection) NuGet package to use NHibernate in a medium trust environment.

Comment: I tryed it too... It added reference to the NHibernate.DependencyInjection.dll in my project but still throwing the SecurityException.
Have it any prerequisite?

Comment: @Rippo that's odd. Why would there be a package for 3.3.1 then? In any case, remember that not all "medium trust" configurations are the same.

Comment: That's a question you need to ask Randy, I believe he uses it for other reasons than for medium trust. https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2857

Comment: Really, the trust configuration in my hosting aren't medium, it's custom. NH 3.31 worked.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate supports medium trust, please read [this article](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/run-in-medium-trust.aspx).

It describes how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried all suggestion to fix it (including DependencyInjection), 
but only one helped me:

I've added following code to my Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseReflectionOptimizer = false;
    ...
}
```

And disabled batch in configuration file (last property)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=........</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">0</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Note, this should cause performance issues

Comment: For the "System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission", using NHibernate or ActiveRecord, the first code with application start or AR initialization resolve the problem!


    This loved line "NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseReflectionOptimizer = false;"


Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a more detailed error message so we can diagnose further. In your web.config add this in the `system.webserver`

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
```

Hopefully this will give you a full stack trace and from there should allow you to debug further.

You may also need to add this

`<customErrors mode="Off" />` in `system.web` (I can't remember)